# Two terminal windows open up when I start my Ubuntu app with GNOME

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sh, gnome

I have created a simple terminal application and want to use a simple desktop icon in Ubuntu with GNOME. Currently I have created a .desktop file with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=My App
Icon=/opt/my-app/icon.png
Path=/opt/my-app
Exec=x-terminal-emulator --title "My App" -e "bash -c '/opt/my-app/MyApp;$SHELL'"
StartupNotify=false
X-UnityGenerated=true
Terminal=true
Categories=Utility
```

So far, this has worked well for me. I've created this simple shell script to put it in place:

```
APP_NAME=my-app
APP_BINARY=MyApp
APP_INSTALLATION_PATH=/opt/$APP_NAME

# create app dir
echo "Creating application directory..."
sudo mkdir -p $APP_INSTALLATION_PATH

# place icon and binary
echo "Placing icon in application directory..."
sudo cp resources/icon.png $APP_INSTALLATION_PATH/icon.png

echo "Setting permission for ${APP_INSTALLATION_PATH}/icon.png..."
sudo chmod 644 $APP_INSTALLATION_PATH/icon.png

echo "Placing binary in application directory..."
sudo cp build/MyApp $APP_INSTALLATION_PATH/$APP_BINARY

echo "Setting executable permission for ${APP_BINARY}..."
sudo chmod +x $APP_INSTALLATION_PATH/$APP_BINARY

echo "Placing desktop icon..."
cp resources/$APP_NAME.desktop $HOME/.local/share/applications/$APP_NAME.desktop

echo "Setting executable permission for ${APP_NAME}.desktop..."
chmod +x $HOME/.local/share/applications/$APP_NAME.desktop

echo "${APP_BINARY} is now installed..."
```

So what's the problem then? The problem is when I start the application it opens two terminal windows. And both terminals are open in the "regular" terminal icon with two more "dots".

What I simply want is to make my icon have one "dot" appearing there, also that the terminal window shows the title of the app as well. This does not work currently.

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: Try using `Terminal=false`. Or get rid of the call to `x-terminal-emulator`, since that's what `Terminal=True` does automatically.

Comment: @Barmar: it's not, strictly, off topic here. This is stuff you need to deal with when you create a program, and so a bash script to install stuff falls within the scope of this site.  In addition, moderators generally don't bother migrating posts that the OP could just self-delete and repost.

Comment: At any rate, it could be that AskUbuntu or Unix get you better answers, at which point it is easier (and ofter *much* faster) to just delete here and re-post there, provided that you don't get (upvoted) answers in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Terminal=true
```

to

```
Terminal=false
```

You're already creating a terminal with the `x-terminal-emulator` command, you don't need to tell Gnome to create one as well.